# Windows 8 randomly shuts down after installing Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, shutdown, bios

The title says most of it. I believe this is a BIOS issue. Upon startup I have several options to boot into, including:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 33.11.0-15-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 33.11.0-15-generic (recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console115200)
*Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
*Windows Boot UEFI loader
Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)
System Setup
```

*What is the difference between these and which should I be choosing? The first one is the one with the boot issue, although it is a bit rare so any or all of the others may also have the issue as well.

Comment: first one is Ubuntu,after choosing that what error did you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda4)" is the one you want. If you still experience issues with random shutdowns try disabling fast-startup in windows by going to "control panel/hardware and sound/change what power buttons do", and uncheck the box beside "turn on fast startup", then do a shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

you should choose "Windows 8 (loader)"